# servicing interrupts in SPI

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, interrupt-handling, spi

I am working on a project in embedded Linux with beagle bone to transfer 300 bytes of data as one block in one write cycle to a slave (Atmel uC). After having read the Documentation on Spi ie /Documentation/spi I have found that the DMA gets enabled when the data transfer threshold exceeds 160 bytes as mentioned in /drivers/spi/omap2_mcspi.c

I would like to enable flow control based on exchange of const 4 byte values between my beaglebone and Atmel uC. Once I have sent a command say CMD_DATA, the slave responds with RC_RDY. I would like to make a kernel module that services interrupts and calls an interrupt handler every time upon receiving data from slave so that I can check for this ack from slave.

How do I enable interrupts and register interrupt handler for SPI? Any sample codes or tutorials would be helpful. I have looked extensively online and all I found was setting up interrupts for GPIO's

Thanks!

Comment: First, if you want to be monitoring the slave status for an actual byte encoded value, you probably won't be able to use an ordinary DMA engine for that.  So you should probably modify the driver to "break" whatever causes that switchover to DMA at a certain size threshold.  Then you can graft your rate limiting code into the ISR which presumably already exists to handle the subsequent bytes of non-DMA transfer.

Comment: It's not clear how you are going to get back to a positive ACK once you get a negative one - will you keep clocking?  An alternate idea would be to perform the operation in smaller DMA blocks.  Personally, I'd look at having the slave reply with the static level of the MISO line (temporarily driven as a GPIO, or by sending 0x00 vs 0xFF assuming it is glitch free) rather than actual serial data, then you could just check that and pause/abort the DMA, possibly even *within* the DMA engine if it is sophisticated enough.

Comment: I may misconveyed my logic. Below is what I implememted on two 32bit Atmel uc and this seemed to work fine.
1)Enable both master and slave with slave in idle mode.
2)Master sends a command such as 0xAAFFFFFF and the DMA interrupt handler on the slave side gets called on having received data. Based on what state the slave is, it chooses to treat the data as a command or actual data. Seeing that its received a command, it responds with 0xAAAAFFFF indicating to the master that it can send actual blocks of data.

Comment: 3)the DMA interrupt handler gets called on the master side and the master notices this and understands that its got the go ahead to send data. The above is what I want to implement. It's a very simple logic for flow control i believe(although I think I could also use two GPIO lines instead). The DMA shouldn't be problem according to me. What I want is that my module  calls an interrupt handler every time I receive data from the slave on the DMA receive channel for the master.

Comment: Whats got me confused is that, would I have to write a new driver/ could my module take care of this with the existing drivers. IF the module should suffice, how do I enable an interrupt handler for the above mentioned purpose?

Comment: If you only want to know the result of a complete operation, typically you wouldn't do that in the kernel at all.  Instead you would use a blocking transfer operation in userspace, and your calling thread would block waiting on the kernel driver until the DMA operation is complete and has a result for you.

Comment: could you give me an example of this?

Comment: Try to find any bidirectional SPI example for your board.